# Dropping duplicate rows in a Pandas DataFrame based on multiple column values

Tags: python, pandas, drop-duplicates

In a dataframe I need to drop/filter out duplicate rows based the combined columns A and B. In the example DataFrame

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   1   3   9
1   1   2   4   8
2   1   3   5   7
3   1   3   4   6
4   1   4   5   5
5   1   4   6   4
```

rows 2 and 3, and 5 and 6 are duplicates and one of them should be dropped, keeping the row with the lowest value of

```
2 * C + 3 * D
```

To do this, I created a new temporary score column, S

```
df['S'] = 2 * df['C'] + 3 * df['D']
```

and finally to return the index of the minimum value for S

```
df.loc[df.groupby(['A', 'B'])['S'].idxmin()]
del ['S']
```

The result is

```
    A   B   C   D
0   1   1   3   9
1   1   2   4   8
3   1   3   4   6
5   1   4   6   4
```

However, is there a more efficient way of doing this, without having to add (and later drop) a new column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way by using `sort_values()` and `duplicated()`

```
df.loc[~df.sort_values('A',key = lambda x: df['C'].mul(2).add(df['D'].mul(3))).duplicated(subset = ['A','B'])]
```

Output:

```
   A  B  C  D
0  1  1  3  9
1  1  2  4  8
3  1  3  4  6
5  1  4  6  4
```

Answer (score 1):

df.drop_duplicates(subset=['A','B'],inplace=True)

by default, drop_duplicates drops rows (axis=0).

Comment: That will always keep the first row, right? The one to drop depends on columns C and D.

Answer (score 1):

#### Efficient solution for larger dataframes

```
ix = np.argsort(2 * df['C'] + 3 * df['D'])
result = df.iloc[ix].drop_duplicates(['A', 'B'])
```

#### `timeit` analysis

Setup:

```
60000 rows with 10000 different groups
```

Results

```
%%timeit my solution
# 6.75 ms ± 309 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit OP solution
# 595 ms ± 50.1 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```